# i want to access 'ids' of asp.net server controls in for loop.so with single line i can set value to all controls

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
for(int i = 1; i < 5;i++)
{
    label[i].InnerText = info.books[0].title;
}
```

I want something like this to access id's of 5 server controls in loop. 
label1,label2,.....,label5. It is a code behind file.

Comment: It is not very clear what you are trying to do... But a Repeater might help?

Comment: suppose i have 5 controls < asp:LabelID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" ></asp:Label>  < asp:LabelID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label" ></asp:Label> and so on..i want to access 'ids' of controls in loop.so i can access all 5 controls with a single statement.

Comment: Please edit your post to include all the new information.

Answer (score 0):

If you really wanted you can use FindControl

```
for (int i = 1; i < 5; i++)
{
    Label lbl = Page.FindControl("Label" + i) as Label;
    lbl.Text = info.books[0].title;
}
```